# Ionic splash screen and spinner

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen, ionic2

Is there a way to customize spinner in splash screen?
Currently I am using cordova splashscreen plugin and I want to change the color of spinner that appears on the splash screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/splashscreen/SplashScreen.java`, at the top:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.content.res.Resources;
```

And further down the bottom replace with this function:

```
 // Show only spinner in the center of the screen
private void spinnerStart() {
    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            spinnerStop();

            spinnerDialog = new ProgressDialog(webView.getContext());
            spinnerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    spinnerDialog = null;
                }
            });

            spinnerDialog.setCancelable(false);
            spinnerDialog.setIndeterminate(true);


            Resources activityRes = cordova.getActivity().getResources();
            int spinnerResId = activityRes.getIdentifier("customspinner", "drawable", cordova.getActivity().getPackageName());
            Drawable customSpinner = activityRes.getDrawable(spinnerResId);

            RelativeLayout centeredLayout = new RelativeLayout(cordova.getActivity());
            centeredLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            centeredLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(webView.getContext());
            progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(customSpinner);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            progressBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            centeredLayout.addView(progressBar);

            spinnerDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            spinnerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            spinnerDialog.show();
            spinnerDialog.setContentView(centeredLayout);
        }
    });
}
```

In `platforms/android/res/drawable` - add the folder if it doesn't exists - add the file `customspinner.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">
        <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
            android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:angle="0"
             />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Original answer here: [Cordova splash screen change spinner color on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026019/cordova-splash-screen-change-spinner-color-on-android)

Comment: is it possible to change with any other spinning (or other Loader) with default Spinner in Splash Screen.

Comment: @Neotrixs you may put any code you want in `customspinner.xml` to create a different loader, it doesn't have to be a spinner. The file is how you define the loader.

Answer (score -1):

well providing color to `ion-spinner` isn't difficult. You can do like this
*css*

```
.spinner svg {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  stroke: #444;
  fill: #444;
}
```

*html*

```
<ion-spinner icon="circles "class="spinner-energized"></ion-spinner>
```

as per [Ionic Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/).

Comment: I am using cordova splash screen plugin which comes with a property i.e ' <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/> ' to add a spinner. The solution that you have provided is for ionic spinner which is not being used in this case.

Comment: You have provided any code then it was hard to guess what you are using and what you are getting. But can you tell me what type of spinner you are using on the screen. And Why you are **not using ionic spinner** .

Comment: This can't be used with default splash screen.