# Splashscreen spinner change color

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building an android webapp using cordova and framework7 for an existing drupal site. I'm currently using cordova-plugin-splashscreen for the app's spashscreen. I am able to enable or disable the spinner but not change the color of it.

I want to change the color of the spinner and also change the position to bottom of the screen.

I have tried the solution in this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202147/ionic-splash-screen-and-spinner/37226445), but its not working. please don't mark this as duplicate and give a solution.

This is the part where i include the spinner in config.xml

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerColor" value="#242424"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2" />
<engine name="android" spec="~6.0.0" />
```

Note: In the cordova site, the SplashScreenSpinnerColor preference is given as a quirk for windows.

Comment: Show your config.xml or at least the part where you setup the splash

Comment: @Eric i have included the part of where i setup the splash

Comment: Try this link: [cordova plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202147/ionic-splash-screen-and-spinner/37226445)

Comment: @ShashankVerma, i already tried that, but no use.